# Showing blank page after clicking on Magento WYSIWYG editor image insert button

Tags: magento-1.9

When I click on WYSIWYG editor image insert button it is only showing a blank page. Below screen shot is for reference.

[image]

Comment: I am also facing this issue, It would be great if you can share the solution for this.

Answer (score 1):

This is likely due to your host applying a Web Application Firewall which is blocking it from displaying.

The issue is caused because you will need to apply the 5344 patch available here:

https://www.magentocommerce.com/products/downloads/magento/

Once patched your image browser should then display correctly.

Also, it's worth checking that your browser/system has flash installed as this is still (unfortunately) used in the image browser.

Comment: How will I deploy new patch? Will it hamper my live site any how ?

Comment: I have done the same but still no resolved this issue.

Comment: Check my edit, it may be just an issue with flash. Do you have Flash installed and working correctly in your browser?

Answer (score 0):

If anyone is having a similar issue, I believe that the reason was because I had x-frame-options: DENY however, Magento needs X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN in order to allow the frame to populate. God bless you!

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41581104/magento-1-9-2-4-magento-connect-manager-not-showing-installation-terminal/41584438#41584438